# Bit manipulations/operations calculator?

Tags: bit-manipulation

I am getting into bit manipulation in C/C++.

Is there a good calculator or program (executable or online), that makes it relatively convenient to study & test bit procedures?

I can do same work in Visual Studio or Eclipse, but relatively small program is easier and more convenient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use bincalc by Ding Zhaojie.  It conveniently lets you see what's going on in hex and binary (and decimal if you care), and has a nice gadget for inputting binary or flipping bits.

- http://sites.google.com/site/bincalc/

Free, but no source.

Answer (score 4):

The calculator, `calc`, in Windows 7 has a 'Programmer' view (Alt + 3).  It has most of the operations for bit manipulations.

Answer (score 2):

[bitwisecmd.com](http://bitwisecmd.com) Supports conversion from decimal to binary and hehadecimal numbers as well as basic bitwise operations as AND, OR, XOR, NOT, left shift, right shift. Neatly arranges bits in binary numbers so you can see how this stuff works.

Comment: Finally, a free form textual web-based bitwise calculator! This is definitely the best of the options listed here.

Answer (score 1):

I use a good online tool that supports all the bitwise operations, so you don't need to install anything: http://www.convertforfree.com/bitwise-calculator/

This tool saved me a lot of time and effort.

Answer (score 0):

Use this [tool](https://truthtablemaker.com/).  It has a free online truth table generator as well as a calculator for bitwise operations.